# Detect if current page is the web root

Tags: php, laravel

Looking for the simplest way of checking via PHP if the current page is the root '/'

I only want to show a certain element on the root of my website, but using a blade template and have this certain element in the template for all pages.

Thanks.

E.g.

```
<?php
  if ($page == $root) {
    // show
  }
?>
```

If it helps I am using Laravel 4.2.

Comment: Not sure about laravel.but, you are not _comparing_.you are _assigning_.use `==` or `===` instead.

Comment: When you refer to "root", you mean the "root folder" or the "route root"?

Comment: @himal Sorry, typo! And I mean the main index. So domain.com or if I am on localhost testing locally then that too.

Comment: `Request::url() == url('/')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri() == '/')
{
    // You're on the root route
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Within the **Blade** templating of Laravel, the following would suffice

```
@if(Request::is('/'))
    // The condition you require
@endif
```

Answer (score 20):

You can also do it quickly the following way

```
if(Request::is('/')) {
 //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply try

> `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/')`

Comment: Perfect solution as compatible with historic versions and probably future proof too...

Answer (score 2):

Use anywhere. Larave Helper function

```
if(request()->is('/')){
    //put your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or something like this if you name your route name.

```
if(Route::getCurrentRoute()->name('home')) {
   // code
}
```